# Copy does not prompt for overwriting existing file

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

The following command (when run in windows terminal) does prompt for overwriting existing file

```
copy myfile.bat myfile_2.bat
```

Output: `Overwrite myfile_2.bat? (Yes/No/All):`

To avoid prompt, one can just add `/y` option.

However, when the same command is run from within a batch-file, it always assumes the `/y` option, even when not explicitly given.

Why?

Comment: You've used one command only, so reading the help for that command would have meant your question was solved. Most commands have usage information, so opening a Command Prompt and entering `Copy /?` should have been your first port of call before asking here.

Comment: @Compo I did read through the `/?`, but the question was more about the different behaviour using console vs. script. (And to be honest, I didn't pay too much attention to `/-Y`, even if I would have, the question is still valid)

Comment: Well in the US version of Windows I run, the help file for the `COPY` command clearly states this: **Default is
to prompt on overwrites unless COPY command is being executed from
within a batch script.**

Comment: @Squashman Really? What Win version?

Comment: Thanks for the unmotivated downvote

Comment: @niCkcAMel, confirmed on Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 10, Windows 2008 Server, Windows 2012 Server and Windows 2016 server.

Comment: @Squashman how about win 3.11? Seriously though, I just must have missed those lines in `/? `

Comment: @niCkcAMel, I think you mean DOS 6.22 as Windows 3.11 ran on top of that. I ditched my VM of that a few years ago.

Comment: @Squashman lol. In a philosophical way, I haven't received an answer as to "why" this is the behavior of `copy`. In a sense, I have stated what the default behavior is *unless* from script. But why? ;)

Comment: @niCkcAMel, I will see if I can find Bill's phone number and ask him why he decided to program it that way.  My best guess would be that batch files are used for automation so it would be assumed you want to overwrite files. Do you honestly think you can get a logical answer to this without asking the actual person who programmed the executable.

Comment: @Squashman I WAS KIDDING. Jeez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [document](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)

Apparently, in windows 2000 and above, the default action is to prompt on overwrite **unless the command is being executed from within a batch file**.

Also mentioned [here](https://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm)

Try this

```
/-Y
```

instead of

```
/Y
```

*/-Y Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.*

Comment: Ahh... `/-Y` . Works! Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It clearly states that in the help file when you type: `copy /?` at a command prompt.